# RESTful service for PUT/PATCH with image upload - testing with Postman

Tags: rest, laravel, postman

I am trying to test an app with *RESTful* services via Postman (awaiting the front-end to be implemented).

The `GET/POST` and `DELETE` requests work as expected, but when it comes to `PUT` and `PATCH` I'm completely stuck.

I have a simple form with several inputs and files (pdf & image). With the `POST` request I simply use the *"form-data"* body to add all needed parameters. But when I try to test the `PUT` one, *"form-data"* detects nothing - with or without a `"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data"` set in the header.

The `PUT` only works with the *"x-www-form-urlencoded"* option for the body, but then I cannot or don't know how to add both files, as I don't have the ability to choose from "Text/File" anymore via Postman's dropdown. Again, adding Content-Type doesn't help a bit.

I tried simulating `POST` with a `"_method"="PUT"` both as a URL parameter and as a form input, but it just creates new item instead of updating existing one (with correct route applied).

```
# Updated with the routes (standard Laravel routes for RESTful services)

GET     | api/v1/Collection             | api.v1.collection.index
POST    | api/v1/collection             | api.v1.collection.store
GET     | api/v1/collection/create      | api.v1.collection.create
GET     | api/v1/collection/{item}      | api.v1.collection.show
PUT     | api/v1/collection/{item}      | api.v1.collection.update
DELETE  | api/v1/collection/{item}      | api.v1.collection.destroy
GET     | api/v1/collection/{item}/edit | api.v1.collection.edit
```

I realize I have to use a hidden input with *_method/PUT* as key-value, but I have no idea where to add it in Postman. I can only see two options: text input or file.

What am I missing? 
I can provide screenshots upon request. Thanks.

Comment: Frontend you mean "browser" kinda frontend or like iPhone/Android app? If the browser one you dont need to care about PUT/PATCH/DELETE because only POST/GET is supported and Laravel cheats this by "_method" hidden field. If you knew all this then I am just pointing out :) So use POST method as postman but insert "hidden" input key value pair with PUT. If that fails edit question and show us your routes I bet that is what you are doing wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @Kyslik I added my routes and I do get your point, but I don't know **where** in Postman to add the hidden input.

Comment: There is no "hidden" input in postman from frontend point of view it's <input type=hidden... But in Postman use simple text field; or search postman github issue page; try different REST testing tool. Does ever "update" method triggers? What are your middlewares? What package do you use for api? Try listing all relevant packages.

Comment: @Kyslik The UPDATE request works every time when there aren't any files to be send over. I tried using Postman's simple text fields to simulate the hidden _method, but instead of updating the record a new one is always created. With Laravel I use the built in resource controllers, so there aren't any special packages in particular for my API. I've also tried using Charles instead of Postman, but didn't progress much with the issue. Anyway, if and when I find a solution, I'll update my question.

Comment: Take a look at curl I know it might be a bit hardcore, but there is plenty tutorials on how to use it, craft your request and see what you get back. And remeber you will never send any other request method than GET/POST (using browsers). If that fails you are doing something wrong in controller.